# Could not initialize class sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment

Tags: java, graphics, awt, noclassdeffounderror

In my code i do:

```
java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames()
```

But some user got this stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.awt.Win32GraphicsEnvironment
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.createGE(GraphicsEnvironment.java:102)
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment(GraphicsEnvironment.java:81)
```

I have some information about his system:
*Windows 7 (6.1), amd64 architecture, java version: 1.8.0_40*

What is the problem? Is it something graphic driver related?

Comment: Is the machine running as a headless environment?

Comment: It's Windows, so unlikely. Machine however does act as a server (running modified JBoss). A friend of mine said that restarting it should help, so this is what I'll reply to the user.